# What is the etiquette when it comes to questions answered in comments?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, comments

I see a user attracting downvotes in two places now:

eg: [Fetch License from sandbox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/24239/320)

eg: [Error while trying Webservice](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/24278/320)

A casual observer may see those answers as parroting of others' commentary, so what is the best practice when it comes to raising an answer that has already been distilled in a comment thread?

Answer (score 12):

Answers belong in answers not comments, I don't see why those answers are being downvoted.

Comment: I totally agree, but nonetheless I feel unhealthy behaviours in these downvotes.

Answer (score 12):

I normally post a comment suggesting the commentary be moved to an answer.

Comment: Yeah I generally ask the commenter to turn it into an answer. Somtimes I wonder why they commented in the first place though, some people just need to commit themselves :)

Comment: Our [answer ratio of 1.7 is "Okay"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce) which is lower than the 2.5 considered "Good".  I say, err on the side of posting an answer.

Comment: @PeterKnolle we actually went down to 1.6 now, what have you done ;)

Answer (score 7):

[Fetch License from sandbox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24239/fetch-license-from-sandbox)

Not sure what the big deal is here?

sfdcfox commented first @ 12:03 my time. He nailed the problem on the head what became obvious from the following comments. And finally posted a proper answer @ 12:33. I wouldn't call it stealing from anybody. Maybe the downvotes are about lack of links?

"parroting of others' commentary" - yes, his own...

---

[Error while trying Webservice](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/24278)

Ok, that could be "stolen", user320 was "first". But seeing that:

- OP provided clarification at 16:00 (again - my time)
- arguably he should have made it an answer, not a comment (even if he'd wait with accepting to recognize the help)
- sfdcfox posted at 16:24
- user320 posted a comment at 19:27 (and it's a comment that cost him some effort, I'm always annoyed when I have to make pretty links in comments); it should be an answer even if it'd be somewhat of a duplicate
- the answer is still not accepted

I wouldn't make too much fuss about it. Looks like so-so example of collaboration overall but should it really attract downvotes and / or retaliation?

Well, "user320" - do **you** hold grudge or something? Robbed of rep points? I somehow doubt that. Maybe we have some lone cowboys with wicked sense of justice...

---

It's not a speed contest, it's not [fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141638/the-fast-and-the-furious) (anymore). Long term reusability of answers should be (ideally) the goal.

With 200 daily rep cap and only +10 for upvote / -2 for a downvote (& -1 for the downvoter) I feel bit angry every time I'm downvoted but I get over it quickly :)

And with his almost 20K rep I doubt he even felt it ;)

Comment: ya got me ;) raised this meta for guidance and [asked](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/24280/320) @sfdcfox to edit so I may retract

Comment: @user320 I'm definitely not trying to steal anyone else's thunder. I use the site to help people, and questions with no official answers don't help people. I scour the unanswered list to see if I can provide answers anywhere, and comment-answered questions still show up in the unanswered list, which makes me look at them over and again. If the person who supplied the correct answer would make their answer an answer, or even if the OP would make a comment the answer, then I wouldn't have to, and I could focus on questions with no actual answers!

Comment: good call @sfdcfox cheers