# Attributing an answer to a commenter

Tags: discussion

I've inadvertently answered a question along the same lines as a suggested answer that appears in the comments in the question [Problem Invoking Batch from Button](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29711/problem-invoking-batch-from-button/29728).

Bad [etiquette](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-is-the-etiquette-when-it-comes-to-questions-answered-in-comments) on my part as the commenter hasn't had much of a chance to create an answer based on the comment. Maybe after several days of inactivity I'd have no issue with this, but ~4 hours is a bit to quick.

Is it possible to formally attribute the answer to the commenter so they can get the points? 
I.e. I basically make the answer appear as if they created it, maybe with edits from me.

Or, am I better off switching to communitywiki or deleting my answer if the commenter posts a separate answer that covers the same thing.

I know it only comes down to imaginary internet points, but I don't want to deter others from participating in the site. That said, I'm reluctant to delete a possible answer that might help someone in the future.

Comment: +1 for Imaginary Internet Points ^^

Comment: Maybe it is more of a feature request. Often I would like to allocate the Rep points to another user who put in the effort with comments or a linked blog post etc... I guess such a system might be open to abuse.

Comment: Try http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=allocate+rep

Comment: Interesting. Maybe I could put a bounty on the Question and have it allocated to the other user? Maybe it all just becomes too complicated. I think community wiki will be best of the available options.

Answer (score 4):

I applaud you for bringing this up. Often, I'll make comments initially about a new post or ask questions because I don't feel comfortable posting an "answer" based on the information that's been provided.

Recently, the questions I asked provided the solution to the problem as acknowledged in a reply to my comments. I never posted them as an "answer". I'm not primarily here for "points", but instead to learn and to help others when I can.

Not to hijack your thread, but would it be beneficial to the site (particularly for those who might search for answers to similar questions in the future) if I went back and posted my comments as an answer?

Since your post is essentially related to comments and their impact on this site, do you feel we should make an attempt to consolidate them into our answers at some point in time when they've added value?

Comment: Yes, you should post it as answer. I think that would be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: Seconded, definitely turn comments into answers. When I arrive back via a Google search a year or two later it is much easier to go straight to the answer rather than read through the comment thread. If the commenter didn't come back after a long period of time it is fair game for someone else to format as an answer. Maybe give credit to the commenter or use community wiki in the answer.

Comment: Oddly, I couldn't find the post when I went to look for it. I found what may have been the post, but the other comments are now gone. I remember the OP's response having followed comments by metadaddy that I can't find in anything in my history. Perhaps the post was removed? The only thing I found that may have been it was now on hold. So this particular one seems to have either disappeared or "updated" itself into something else. LOL. However, I thank you for the guidance and will use it in the future.